# How can I select the first and last week of each month in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have monthly data with several observations per day. I have day, month and year variables. How can I retain data from only the first and the last 5 days of each month? I have only weekdays in my data so the first and last five days of the month changes from month to month, ie for Jan 2008 the first five days can be 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 7th and 8th of the month.
Below is an example of the data file. I wasn't sure how to share this so I just copied some lines below. This is from Jan 2, 2008.
Would a variation of first.variable and last.variable work? How can I retain observations from the first 5 days and last 5 days of each month?
Thanks.

```
1 AA  500 B 36.9800 NH 2 1 2008 9:10:21 
2 AA  500 S 36.4500 NN 2 1 2008 9:30:41
3 AA  100 B 36.4700 NH 2 1 2008 9:30:43 
4 AA  100 B 36.4700 NH 2 1 2008 9:30:48 
5 AA  50  S 36.4500 NN 2 1 2008 9:30:49
```

Comment: Define first week and last week?  First in the data?  First based on the calendar and weeks starting on Monday?  Does it have to be a full week (ie. M-F)?

Comment: You can use NWDOM to find the first week easily, but not sure about how to find the last week? Is it the last full week? Please post better sample data that details you issue as well as what you've tried so far. For first/last 5 days look at INTNX function especially the fourth parameter, alignment.

Comment: @BetsyB, agree with previous comment, please add some data example which you want to get.

Comment: I tried to simplify the question. I just need the code to identify the first 5 and last 5 values of the day variable for each month and retain those observations (there are multiple observations for each day). I don't need Mon-Fri weeks. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have data for each working day _(as of a certain start date till a certain end date)_?

Comment: Yes, I have several observations for each working day in a month. I have no data for weekends or other holidays. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to examine the data and determine the minimum 5 and maximum 5 values then you can use `PROC SUMMARY`.  You could then merge the result back with the data to select the records.

So if your data has variables YEAR, MONTH and DAY you can make a new data set that has the top and bottom five days per month using simple steps.

```
proc sort data=HAVE (keep=year month day) nodupkey 
     out=ALLDAYS;
   by year month day;
run;
proc summary data=ALLDAYS nway;
 class year month;
 output out=MIDDLE
   idgroup(min(day) out[5](day)=min_day)
   idgroup(max(day) out[5](day)=max_day)
  / autoname ;
run;
proc transpose data=MIDDLE out=DAYS (rename=(col1=day));
  by year month;
  var min_day: max_day: ;
run;
proc sql ;
  create table WANT as 
    select a.* 
    from HAVE a 
    inner join DAYS b
    on a.year=b.year and a.month=b.month and a.day = b.day
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you. Intnx function a bit confusing to me. I understand this code better. However, this selects the first day 5 times and the last day five times. It's probably because I have more than 5 observations for each day. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You might need to select distinct dates first.

Comment: Added step to find distinct dates first.

Comment: I tried it again. The code creates min_day_1 min_day_2 etc through min_day_5 but assigns the same day for all of those which is the first calendar day in my data. Same thing for the last 5 days. It assigns the very last calendar day to all 5.

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can leave out the transpose and  `inner join MIDDLE on a.year=b.year and a.month=b.month and (a.day le b.min_day6 or b.max_day6 le a.day)`

Comment: @DirkHorsten - Good idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
/****
get some dates to play with
****/
data dates(keep=i thisdate);
offset = input('01Jan2015',DATE9.);
do i=1 to 100;
    thisdate = offset + round(599*ranuni(1)+1); *** within 600 days from offset;
    output;
end;
format thisdate date9.;
run;

/**** 
BTW: intnx('month',thisdate,1)-1 = first day of next month. Deduct 1 to get the last day
                                  of the current month.
     intnx('month',thisdate,0,"BEGINNING") = first day of the current month
****/
proc sql;
create table first5_last5 AS
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    dates /* replace with name of your data set */
WHERE
    /* replace all occurences of 'thisdate' with name of your date variable */
   ( intnx('month',thisdate,1)-5 <= thisdate <= intnx('month',thisdate,1)-1 )
   OR
   ( intnx('month',thisdate,0,"BEGINNING") <= thisdate <= intnx('month',thisdate,0,"BEGINNING")+4 )
ORDER BY
    thisdate;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you but I was not able to get this to work. I tried to clarify my original question. Why do you use 01jan2015? Sorry, I'm not the best programmer, that's why I ask.

Comment: your condition is equivalent to `thisdate lt intnx('month',thisdate,0,'BEGIN')+5 OR thisdate gt intnx('month',thisdate,0,'END')-5`, in which `ntnx('month',thisdate,0,'BEGIN')` _(the beginning of 0 months before th ebeginning of thisDate)_ is the first day of the month

Comment: Is this correct? To my understanding, for a month starting with a saturday, this will only generate 3 days at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

**Create some data with the desired structure**;

```
Data inData (drop=_:); * froget all variables starting with an underscore*;
    format date yymmdd10. time time8.;

    _instant = datetime(); 
    do _i = 1 to 1E5;
        date = datepart(_instant);
        time = timepart(_instant);
        yy = year(date);
        mm = month(date);
        dd = day(date);         

        *just some more random data*;
        letter = byte(rank('a') +floor(rand('uniform', 0, 26)));

        *select week days*;
        if weekday(date) in (2,3,4,5,6) then output;

        _instant = _instant + 1E5*rand('exponential');
    end;
run;
```

**Count the days per month**;

```
proc sql;
    create view dayCounts as
    select yy, mm, count(distinct dd) as _countInMonth
    from inData
    group by yy, mm;
quit;
```

**Select the days**;

```
data first_5(drop=_:) last_5(drop=_:);
    merge inData dayCounts;
    by yy mm;
    _newDay = dif(date) ne 0;

    retain _nrInMonth;
    if first.mm then _nrInMonth = 1;
    else if _newDay then _nrInMonth + 1;

    if _nrInMonth le 5 then output first_5;
    if _nrInMonth gt _countInMonth - 5 then output last_5;
run;
```

Comment: Remark, if by accident one of the first working days has no observations, this sollution will still give you 5 working days with observations. Is that what you desired?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! There was an answer where I understood the code better which solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `INTNX()` function. You can use `INTNX('month',...)` to find the beginning and ending days of the month and then use `INTNX('weekday',...)` to find the first 5 week days and last five week days.

You can convert your month, day, year values into a date using the `MDY()` function.  Let's assume that you do that and create a variable called `TODAY`.  Then to test if it is within the first 5 weekdays of last 5 weekdays of the month you could do something like this:

```
first5 = intnx('weekday',intnx('month',today,0,'B'),0) <= today
      <= intnx('weekday',intnx('month',today,0,'B'),4) ;
last5 = intnx('weekday',intnx('month',today,0,'E'),-4) <= today 
     <= intnx('weekday',intnx('month',today,0,'E'),0) ;
```

Note that those ranges will include the week-ends, but it shouldn't matter if your data doesn't have those dates.
But you might have issues if your data skips holidays.

Comment: As `intnx('weekday',intnx('month',today,0,'B'),0) <= today` for every weekday, `first5 = today <= intnx('weekday',intnx('month',today,0,'B'),4)` and the like for last5.

Comment: To choose between this answer and mine, you must indeed decide what to do with holidays (and days when the observer was unavailable and days when nothing happened).